# How to avoid redundant iCloud photo upload from iPhone when the same photos have been uploaded from Mac?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, icloud, photos

I have iCloud Photo Library enabled on Mac as well as iPhone so all my photos remain synced. Yesterday I imported a bunch of photos (~200) from iPhone to Mac with Photos app import feature. Then I allowed the new photos to be uploaded to iCloud from Mac. My phone didn't have wifi access at this time so phone didn't upload those, as expected. Now when I connect the phone to wifi all the photos seem to be being uploaded from phone as well ( as seen in Settings > Photos & Camera on iPhone. It says `Uploading 268 items` there), when they've already been uploaded to cloud from Mac.

Is there any way to allow upload only from one of the devices? I was hoping iCloud sync will be able to figure this out and only upload the photos that require uploading.

What's the best I can do to avoid redundant uploads?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Can you clarify _Now when I connect the phone to wifi all the photos seem to be being uploaded from phone as well_? How do they _seem_ to be uploaded? You haven't explained what's actually happening to make you think this is what's going on?

Comment: **( as seen in Settings > Photos & Camera on iPhone)**. It says `Uploading 268 items` there.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question to clarify. Do you know if it's actually uploading the 268 items? What I'm getting at is that both the iPhone and iCloud won't know _not_ to upload these photos until they have communicated with each other. What we need to establish is whether after a few minutes or so the _Uploading 268 items_ message is gone because iCloud has established "I've already got these - no need to upload them". In other words, you may not actually have any duplicates in your iCloud Photo Library. Have you checked on [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com/) to see if you do?